# Is it possible to detect Mouse Click on Browser froma cgi C++ Application

Tags: javascript, c++, winapi, cgi

I want to know if it is possible to detect when a use presses the left mouse button on webpage made with cgi using C++. I am **NOT** asking for a code.

If I use **Win32** **api** to detect mouse click, will it **work** on a **webpage** when a user **visit** the page with **Windows Os**?

Another option I have is to **generate** **javascript** code that could do that but I prefer doing it using **Windows API**. I don't know if I am dreaming but has anyone ever tried this before?

Comment: HTTP is stateless. Once the CGI application has generated a web page, it is sent to the client. After this point, the web server (and CGI application) is out of the game. It appears like you lack very basic understanding, of how a web server works.

Comment: I know the basic of web servers. I know that it servers pages. If I have a while loop, the page will still be waiting to receive more information. I want to know if you can continue to be waiting for a key press from the while loop.

Comment: HTTP is stateless. The client sends a `HTTP GET` command and receives a response. And that's it. If you need the client to respond to events and communicate back with the server, you need some sort of script running **on the client**. Either way, once the page is served, the CGI application is through, and most certainly not running any code servicing this request. You should write a simple CGI application to get a basic understanding of how web servers operate.

Comment: So you can't detect a key press from generated javascript then notify serer through post/get later on? The post/get receiver will be a cgi program?

Comment: I guess that was the *"some sort of script running on the client"* part of my previous comment. It seems we are going in circles.

Comment: Oh ok. i get it. I thought when you said that, you meant that I would need a plugin running on the client's browser. That wasn't clear to me but now it is.  But do you think that this is a good idea to do this?

Comment: @Programmer - it's an awful idea. It just wont work. Just detect the mouse events with the browser and then send the co-ordinates of these events to the CGI/PHP/ASP,_whatever_ back-end. It will work on all OSs,not just Winblows.